# Zend Framework 2 get identity in view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to display the user cart amount on each page of an e-shop application.

To achieve that, I have created a view helper but I don't know how to get the user's identity ...

```
<?php

namespace ...;

use ...\Services\Traits\OrdersServicesTrait;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CartAmount extends AbstractHelper {

    use OrdersServiceTrait;

    public function __invoke()
    {

        // needs identity here ...

        $amount = $this->getOrdersService()->fetchCartAmount($user);

        if (!$amount)
            return 0;

        return $amount;
    }

}
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally a dependency injection example would be needed here, but in this case, `$this->view->identity()` (calling the identity view helper) should give you what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, it works great ! I'm new with ZF2, what do you recommend to achieve this job better ?

Comment: In this case that approach is just fine. If you need to access other things in your view helpers you'll need to use dependency injection to supply them.

Comment: I have followed your tips and I inject an Auth Service in my view helper. Thanks again